# CCLayerPanZoom extension and isometric tilemap

Tags: cocos2d-x, cclayerpanzoom

I have problems with getting tile coordinates from touch location when I'm using `CCLayerPanZoom` extension. It works good without zoom (when scale is `1.0f`), but if I zoom in or out it returns weird coordinates. Here is my `tilePosFromLocation` method:

```
CCPoint pos = ccpSub(location, _panZoomLayer->getPosition());
float halfMapWidth = tileMap->getMapSize().width * 0.5f;    
float mapHeight = tileMap->getMapSize().height;     
float tileWidth = tileMap->getTileSize().width;     
float tileHeight = tileMap->getTileSize().height;   
CCPoint tilePosDiv = CCPointMake(pos.x / tileWidth, pos.y / tileHeight); 
float inverseTileY = mapHeight - tilePosDiv.y;
float posX = (int)(inverseTileY + tilePosDiv.x - halfMapWidth); 
float posY = (int)(inverseTileY - tilePosDiv.x + halfMapWidth);
posX = MAX(0, posX); 
posX = MIN(tileMap->getMapSize().width - 1, posX);  
posY = MAX(0, posY); 
posY = MIN(tileMap->getMapSize().height- 1, posY); 
pos=ccp(posX, posY);
return pos;
```

If I use directyl `tileMap->setScale()` instead of the extension, code above works if I multiply tile dimensions with current map scale amount. I would use it instead of `CCLayerPanZoom` but I can not make smooth and nice zooming without this extension.

Any advice how to make it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do This..

```
location=_panZoomLayer->convertToNodeSpace(location); //location is touchLocation ..after convertToGL


convertToNodeSpace method will handle any changes like position or scaling to layer
```